# Adaptive Optics?

Tags: observational-astronomy, optics

I get the general idea of adaptive optics. The light from an object distorted by differences in the earth's atmosphere, and a telescope with AO tries to compensate for this distortion by various mechanisms.

Is there a good resource for more in depth overview on the systems and the physics behind them?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand and have a question about? Have you read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optics?

Comment: Wiki was the first place I looked at, but I wanted more in depth than that.

I was looking for exactly what Dieudonne provided, a good recommendation on reading material

Comment: Haha did you down vote my question @Aaron?

Comment: Yes, which is why I added the comment. The link provided by @Dieudonne is listed as further reading in the Wikipedia article. There are many resources (aside from those linked in the Wikipedia article) and many different implementations of AO systems on telescope so it is hard to recommend a specific resource.

Comment: Exactly, there are more resources out there than what is listed on Wiki, and many things cited on wiki are not overviews of the topic as a whole but specific aspects, thus why I was asking for a recommendation...

Comment: I found http://www.ctio.noao.edu/~atokovin/tutorial/intro.html this tutorial very helpful of obtaining intuition about AO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are of course books about adaptive optics. For instance:
[Tyson, R. Principles of Adaptive Optics, (2010).](http://books.google.nl/books?id=x1PUYBvHHqcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Principles%20of%20Adaptive%20Optics&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api)